# Property was not found on the entity during an insert, update, or delete operation?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a GridView that is tied to an EntityDataSource. Most columns are normal bound columns, but two are itemtemplates. When I attempt a delete on one of the rows I receive the following message:

> "A property named 'Building1.building_name' was not found on the entity during an insert, update, or delete operation. Check to ensure that properties specified as binding expressions are available to the data source."

I'm not sure how it is possible that this isn't available, since it displays the element just fine when I'm just viewing - it just throws the error when I attempt deleting a row?

Answer (score 1):

Binding expressions on the entity model seem to be case sensitive. So, from my experience `Bind("field")` is not the same as `Bind("Field")`.

In other words, check your model for the right case when manually typing out these expressions.

Hope this is helpful for others visiting regarding the same problem.

Comment: Using all bound fields.